# Why curses don't work nowadays?

Tags: scripture, puranas, curse

We often read in ancient texts that someone cursed somebody else and something bad happened to that person. It is obvious that nowadays if somebody curses somebody else we really don't see any effect of that. Why did these work in the ancient past and why not now?

Comment: First of all we can't verify whether a curse worked or not can we? Secondly, it seems some amount of spiritual merit is required for the one who is cursing for the curse to work. Thirdly, according to scriptures curses are supposed to work even in Kali Yuga.

Comment: @rickross well you can use the scientific method in determining the effectiveness of curses.

Comment: @Rickross I agree with Wikash_ . It is very easy to check if a boon or curse worked depending on how it is worded.Also agree about requiring spiritual merit. I disagree with last point, because I think Parikshit got cursed in Kali Yuga and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Curses are supposed to work even in Kali Yuga and currently we are going through Kali.
The following verse from Parashara Smriti (verse 27, Chapter 1) is relevant here:

> Krite Tatkaalikah saapah Tretaayaam Dasamirdinaih |
>  Dwapare
> Chaikamasena Kallou Sambatsarenatu ||
>
> A curse in Krita takes effect immediately,in Treta it does so in 10
> days time,in Dwapara after 1 month and in Kali it takes effect after 1
> year.

So, we can't say that curses are no longer effective now. Moreover, it is difficult for us to verify whether a particular curse worked or not. And hence it is hard to find empirical evidence to prove that curses don't work now. Therefore, we have to go by what the scriptures say.

Comment: In what way is it hard to test curses empirically if the timespans are well defined?

Comment: How do you follow the particular curse? You need to know someone has uttered a curse for someone. That will be known to those two concerned persons. For others it is not possible to verify whether the curse fructified or not. Also the the curse is supposed to take effect after 1 year. So, even if a curse did not fructify within 1 year we have to wait and we can't say that the curse did not work. Moreover there are other factors. I believe there are some procedures to follow for the curse to work. @GregSchmit

Comment: I think the only practical method is to yourself curse somebody you know so that you can follow the status of the curse after 1 year. Now how practical are such experiments to collect evidences? @GregSchmit That's why I said it's hard.